# Different order of columns in create index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I Want To Create Index In SQL Server in Column1 and Column2 What is the difference of below query in Performance of execute query on MyTable:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_1] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [Column1] ASC,
    [Column2] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_2] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [Column2] ASC,
    [Column1] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference of below query:

THe order? Obviously.

Which has implications.

Of a query is for Column2 in a condition and there is an index Column1, Column2  then - the index will NOT be used.

So, multi row indices are only usefull when the queries they target are having the same rows in the same order. You can miss rows in the query, but only "at the end" and the index will be used, buta field at the beginning.... means index is not used.

Comment: I want to know ordering of column in index is important or no, in performance of executed query.

Comment: Well, then I suggest you READ the answer. And the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

TomTom is correct but let me elaborate his answer. Consider following queries

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 = ? AND Column2 = ?; /* IX_1 will be used */
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column2 = ? AND Column1 = ?; /* IX_1 will be used */ 
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 = ?; /* IX_1 will be used */
```

As long as you provide both column of index in `WHERE` clause order doesn't matter. SQL server will decides on its own. Consider following condition as well.

- All columns of index.
- 1st column of index.

But.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column2 = ? /* IX_2 will be used */
```

For above query MSSQL will use your second index.